# Too Broad is the new Too Localised

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

I found a(slightly annoying) transition issue with the close system. This  deals with questions that had outstanding close votes at the time of the overhaul. While this may not be a problem for Physics.SE (we have around 30), SO et al may experience problems due to this:

At first, I thought that people were VTCing as "to broad" due to the absence of the "too localised" option (and was about to superping them to to give a quick overview of the new system), but then I checked the review queue dates. Turns out that all old  outstanding TL votes have been converted to "too broad". This makes no sense, and may lead to other closevoters voting as too broad (due to the red circles in the VTC dialog).

Instead, in the spirit of "too localized is off topic", why not just convert them to unspecified<sup>1</sup> "off topic" votes? This will encourage users to check out the off topic menu.

Also, I think that if a post has 4 "too broad" votes and only one "off topic" vote, it gets closed as "too broad". Which is absurd if the post is "too localized".

Fix please?

<sup>1. By "unspecified" I mean the default off topic reason -- it has no entry in the submenu and is what old off topic votes are converted into</sup>

Comment: [A custom off-topic reason is placed in a comment, not in a bullet point.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/telOZ.png)

Comment: @Antony I saw that, but IIRC it goes in a bullet point too :/

Comment: Interesting, you're right. It uses the default close reason instead.

Comment: In other words, you’re saying that people are using **Too Broad** to mean **Too Narrow**?

Comment: @tchrist That's what it _looks_ like, but no. The _system_ has replaced all old TL votes with too broad.

Comment: What *is* the correct equivalent for too localised?

Comment: @asad off topic, freeform or otherwise